# 内部ストレージへの音声ファイルの保存

Tags: android

内部ストレージに音声ファイルを保存したくてやり方を調べていたのですが、テキストファイルの保存方法ばかりで音声ファイルの保存方法が出てきませんでした。音声ファイルは内部ストレージに保存できないのでしょうか？できるとするならば一体どのような方法で保存をすればよいのでしょうか？すみませんが、宜しくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. メディアライブラリに追加する方法(MediaStoreという画像や音声ファイルを格納するための汎用APIを使用する方法)
   [Video and Audio Playback and Recording](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Video-and-Audio-Playback-and-Recording)の下の方、`If you wanted to add this audio to the media library on the phone:`からソースコードが参考になる。
   再生方法は[ContentResolver+MediaStoreで音楽ファイルを読み込んでみる](http://thr3a.hatenablog.com/entry/20130905/1378381545)のソースコードあたりを読み取りつつ、頑張ればいけるはず。
2. デコードを使用して文字列に変換する方法
   Base64を使用して一旦文字列に変換した後、ContentProviderに突っ込む。

後、@quesera2さんの方法。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。なるほど、メディアライブラリというものを使用する方法があるのですね。ひとまずリンク先を参考に頑張ってみたいと思います。

Comment: あれから色々やってみているのですが、getContentResolver().insertの行でNullPointerExceptionが発生してしまいます。

values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE, fileName);
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.MIME_TYPE, "audio/3gpp");
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA, path);
        Uri uri = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);

そこで質問があるのですが、「MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE」には保存するファイル名を、「MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA」には保存するフォルダのパスを指定してあげるという認識でよろしいでしょうか？

Comment: お忙しい中、不十分な回答で申し訳ありません。
>「MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE」には保存するファイル名を
→スマホのユーザが目にする曲名なので自由に設定して大丈夫です。
「MediaStore.Audio.Media.‌​DATA」には保存するフォルダのパス
→絶対パスなのでフォルダ名+ファイル名を含みます。
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidMedia/article.html#sound_medialibary
上記ブログ（回答の更にネタ元です。）によれば録音したaudiofileをcreateTmpFileより作成しており、その絶対パスをDATAに設定しております。
携帯からお見苦しい回答となりましたが、以上、ご参照いただければ幸いです。

Comment: いえいえ、こちらこそとても助かっております。ご教授いただいた点を参考にもう一度実装し直したいと思います。

Comment: アドバイスやリンク先などを参考に実装したところ、音声ファイルを保存、再生することができました！本当にありがとうございます！